# Why do skilled players in MW2 use weapons unlocked early on, instead of the later ones?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I noticed that in MW2, the more skilled players (who are usually the mvp in team deathmatch, First in FFA and so on), use weapons that are unlocked early on, instead of the weapons unlocked later in the game.

example: They use MP5 instead of Uzi and intervention instead of EBR.

Also, i noticed in terms of specs (damage, fire rate and so on), some of the earlier weapons have better specs than the later ones.

So why do they choose these weapons?

Comment: Not being a MW2 player, but have played many FPS's it that it could be down to the fact as they start off with them earlier they have more time to practise and get better with them, rather than having to "learn" two or three different guns when the they get unlocked.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question is a bit broad and subjective for our format. This site is intended to be more a place where we help address questions with specific answers rather than discussion-style questions that you'd typically ask on a forum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Call of Duty series, there isn't a ton of focus on balance between weapons in the same class.  Just because a weapon is unlocked later doesn't mean that it is any better than any other weapon in that class.

There are almost always a few clear winners in the weapon lineup in every Call of Duty game, and those tend to be used the most often by the "serious" or "pro" players.

There's also frequently a couple of different types of weapons in a given class.  For instance, some people prefer single shot or 3-shot burst AR's, of which there are relatively few.  You might use the M16 over the AK-47 if you prefer 3-shot burst, for instance.  Similarly, some shotguns are pump action and others are semi-automatic or fully automatic, and some sniper rifles are bolt action and others are semi-automatic, etc.

Also, sometimes you get the 'feel' for a weapon and you prefer it, even if its stats aren't the best, or other weapons unlock.  You may choose an earlier weapon because you've unlocked an attachment you like, or are trying to get a particular challenge or kill count with it.

Comment: To add on to what he said, some weapons just seem to work really well. The UMP45 was way overpowered before (I think) it got nerfed, so you saw it everywhere. The intervention is the sniper of choice for quick scopers because it has the shortest sight-in time.

Answer (score -3):

It's always better to bet a gun with great fire rate that causes less damage. It seems like they're lighter and killing enemies can be done quicker. Those guns are usually the beginning ones like in Modern Warfare 3 and Modern Warfare 2, the UMP45 is unlocked early on. In Black Ops MP5K is also unlocked early. 
They're all unlocked near the beginning and there good guns.

Comment: Please write coherent sentences in answering questions. In addition, your answer is based off of speculation.

Comment: Hey ariel, can you elaborate a bit on this answer with more detailed explanations of how these properties affect the quality of the gun?